# Chi-squared peak analysis

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

For a homework assignment I've been asked to play with the titanic data in R.  We need to show if class had an effect on survival.  A quick visual inspection of the data will show that obviously I believe the chi squared test is sufficient to more conclusively that class had an effect but does not really tell you which one had an effect.

```
> ship = data.frame(Titanic)
> byclass = xtabs(Freq ~ Class + Survived, data = ship)
> byclass
      Survived
Class   No Yes
  1st  122 203
  2nd  167 118
  3rd  528 178
  Crew 673 212
```

I ran chi-squared using `prop.test()`

```
> i_will_survive = as.vector(byclass[c(1:4),2])
> total = as.vector(byclass[c(1:4),1]) + as.vector(byclass[c(1:4),2])
> survival_rate = i_will_survive/total
> prop.test( i_will_survive, total )

    4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  i_will_survive out of total
X-squared = 190.4, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.6246154 0.4140351 0.2521246 0.2395480
```

I know the results are obvious but I would like to do something like a peak analysis.  I want to run the test again but drop each category and rank them by which had the greatest effect on the chi-squared value.  SO I would run it without crew and then 1st and then which ever cause the greatest drop in the chi-squared I would rank as being the most deviant from the null.  Does that make sense to do?

Comment: It may be good enough just to show the proportions of survivors from each group as at the end of your Question. But if you want to show influence on the significant test result, I suggest Pearson residuals as in my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be useful for you to use ***Pearson residuals*** from a chi-squared tests.  Here is a copy of the contingency table, without crew.

```
TBL = matrix(c(122,203, 167,118, 528,178), byrow=T, nrow=3)
TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  122  203
[2,]  167  118
[3,]  528  178
```

As you say a chi.squared test is very highly significant with
P-value very nearly $0.$

```
chi.out = chisq.test(TBL)
chi.out

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 133.05, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The chi-squared statistic $Q$ is the sum of six quantities
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^2 \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}
= \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^2  R^2 = 133.05,$$
where $X_{ij}$ are the observed counts from the table,
$E_{ij}$ are expected counts computed from row and column
totals according to the null hypothesis, and $R_{ij}$ are
the *Pearson residuals.* These values are reclaimed from
`chisq.test` using `$`-notation, as shown below.

```
chi.out$obs
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  122  203
[2,]  167  118
[3,]  528  178
chi.out$exp
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 201.7667 123.2333
[2,] 176.9339 108.0661
[3,] 438.2994 267.7006
chi.out$res
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -5.6156102  7.1855119
[2,] -0.7468164  0.9555966
[3,]  4.2845967 -5.4823999
```

The Pearson residuals are often regarded as a good guide
to which cells in the table made the greatest contribution to $Q,$
where residuals with the highest absolute values are most important.
Pearson residuals are sometimes called *'signed' square roots* of the
*contributions* $R^2$ to $Q.$

Here it is clear that the high survivorship by first-class passengers
made the greatest contributions to $Q.$
So possible answers to your question might be to display something
like The sums of rows of the absolute values or sums of rows of squares of the Pearson
residuals:

```
rowSums(abs(chi.out$res))
[1] 12.801122  1.702413  9.766997

rowSums(chi.out$res^2)
[1] 83.16666  1.47090 48.41448
```

Either way, it is clear that the greatest contribution to $Q$ comes
from the 'first-class' row of the contingency table.